# How can update date in many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Can anyone help me on how to update many to many relationship? I have tasks, user can have many tasks and task can have many users (many to many), What I want to achieve is that in update form admin can assign multiple users to specific task. This is done through HTML multiple select input

This is my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    // this is in main view
    $tasks=Task::all()->load('users');
    $userLogin_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $users=User::all()->where('id','!=',$userLogin_id);
    return view('adminUser.index',compact('tasks','users'));
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
    // to create new task and for who it
    $task =Task::create($request->all());
    $userId=$request['employee'];
    $task->users()->attach($userId);
    return back();
}

public function edit($task_id)
{
    //to go to view that has update code
    $task=Task::find($task_id)->load('users');
    $userLogin_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $users=User::all()->where('id','!=',$userLogin_id);

    return view('adminUser.edit',compact('task','users'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $task_id)
{
    //to update task 
    $user_id=$request['employee'];
    Task::where('id',$task_id)
        ->update(['title'=>$request['title'],
                    'description'=>$request['description'],
                    'status'=>$request['status'],
                    'file_path'=>$request['file_path']]);
    //what i can do complete this method if it is correct
    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

This my user model:

```
public function tasks(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task','Todos','user_id','task_id');
}
```

This my task model:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','todos','task_id','user_id');
}
```

Comment: In the update action is `$request['employee'];`  an array of users ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to update parent/sibling tables when your trying to modify table with relationship.

a documentation is here.

https://laravel.io/forum/10-24-2014-update-two-or-more-table-with-relations

You can actually use the pointer.

eg.

we have 2 Models, `User and UserAddress`, consider that user has many addresses and u bind the `$this->hasMany` relation in a `function address()`

while updating User, you can actually do this.

```
foreach($user->address as $index => $address){
    $address->update(['updated_at',Carbon::now());
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.